# Create date range selector based off dates provided

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL database table that has a field for years. Example of this table could be:

```
registration_date |
------------------
1965
1972
1984
1997
1963
```

On the front end side of things, the user is able to select from a dropdown of year 'ranges'. i.e.

```
1961-1965
1966-1970
1971-1975
```

What is the most effective way of generating this range of dates based on the data available from my database?

I have tried:

```
$row = //year available
while(((int) substr($row, -1)) !== 0) {
 $start_date = $row--;
}

while(((int) substr($row, -1)) !== 6) {
 $end_date = $row++;
}
```

but unfortunately this just hangs as it takes too long to execute.

Comment: I see you are pulling out lot of data from database. You should prepare needed data from database using SQL. Then when you have some dates, you can use php to print them.

Comment: How would I use SQL to create the date ranges, rather than just returning the singular dates then? @vishwakarma09

Comment: It might be slow because of the registration_date duplicates, make sure if its values are unique. Even from 1900 to 2016 is a relatively small array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `min()`, `max()` function to find minimum and maximum value from the database registration_date.
I have used here as php function same you should apply with your query to find `MIN` and `MAX`.
I will provide you same example with array.

```
<?php
$resArr = Array(1965,1972,1984,1997,1963);
$max = max($resArr);
$min = min($resArr);
$diff = (($max - $min)/5) + 1;
while($max % 5 != 0)
{
    $max++;
}
while($min % 5 != 0)
{
    $min--;
}

for($i=0;$i<$diff;$i++)
{
    $start = $min+1;
    $end = $min+5;
    $range = $start."-".$end;
    $rangeArr[] = $range;
    $min = $min+5;
}

foreach($rangeArr as $row)
{
    $flag = 0;
    $tmpArr = explode("-", $row);
    foreach($resArr as $val)
    {
        if($val>=$tmpArr[0] && $val<=$tmpArr[1])
        {
            $flag = 1;
        }
    }

    if($flag)
    {
        $newArr[] = $row;
    }
}

echo "Final Array";
print_r($newArr);
```

**output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1961-1965
    [1] => 1971-1975
    [2] => 1981-1985
    [3] => 1996-2000
)
```

**Online Demo: [Click Here](https://eval.in/645084)**

Comment: check above code it will surely help you. @Humphrey Wilkins

Comment: between 1975 and 1980 there is no date in your `$resArr` array, but it still exists in the `$rangeArr`, but it is not clear for me if it even a problem or not.

Comment: user have not specified to remove that range which not included in their table. However, we can also manage that by using `in_array()` function. @Axidepuy

Comment: @RuchishParikh how would I use in_array() to check that the years are in the ranges?

Comment: Please share your desire output. @HumphreyWilkins

Comment: Only to show the date ranges that there is a date for in the database. So it no date exists between 1971-1975, it wouldnt show that. @RuchishParikh

Comment: Ok, I have update and edit the code. Please check latest answer. It will exact what you want. @HumphreyWilkins

Comment: Please check updated ans and give your feedback. @RyanHipkiss